# AppDelegate.h file not found error is appearing in the header file?

Tags: objective-c, swift

As I am bridging the objective c header file in to swift project. But in header file I am getting the error like `AppDelegate.h` file is not found also the header function not called in the swift `ViewController`. Can anyone help me how to resolve this following error.

```
//objective c header file:
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h> 

#define UNIVERSAL_RESPONDER         UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
#define UNIVERSAL_WINDOW            UIWindow
#define UNIVERSAL_APPLICATION       UIApplication
#define UNIVERSAL_VIEWCONTROLLER    UIViewController
#define UNIVERSAL_TEXTVIEW          UITextView
#define UNIVERSAL_BUTTON            UIButton
#define UNIVERSAL_VIEW              UIView
#define UNIVERSAL_APP_ARGV          char *

#define UNIVERSAL_APP_MAIN(__argc, __argv, __class)  \
    UIApplicationMain(__argc, __argv, nil, __class)

#define UNIVERSAL_TEXTVIEW_SETTEXT(__textView, __text)  \
    __textView.text = text

#define UNIVERSAL_BUTTON_SETCHECKED(__buttonView, __checked)  \
    [__buttonView setSelected: __checked]

#define UNIVERSAL_BUTTON_GETCHECKED(__buttonView)  \
    __buttonView.selected

#endif 

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <SpeechSDK/SpeechRecognitionService.h>


//have to call in swift like this
UNIVERSAL_BUTTON* buttonSel = (UNIVERSAL_BUTTON*)self.buttonGroup[i];
        UNIVERSAL_BUTTON_SETCHECKED(buttonSel, (index == i) ? TRUE : FALSE);
```

Comment: how have you added the bridging header? Have you generated it via creating a new Obj-C file in your project? You should check your build settings for a param named "Objective-C bridging header" and see if points to your bridging header file

Comment: yes i created the separate objective c file and i also added that bridging file in the build setting